# Is selecting a bijection between two equinumerous sets equivalent to choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If we add to the language of $\sf ZF$, a unary predicate $C$, and axiomatize that for every equinumerouse sets $X,Y$ there exists a unique bijection $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that $C(f)$.

Is this prinicple equivalent to choice?

If not, then is it equivalent to some weak form of choice?

Note: the symbol $C$ is to be usable in instances of Separation and Replacement.

Comment: Perhaps obvious: if every infinite set is Dedekind infinite, it implies the axiom of choice (and therefore the axiom of global choice), because then every infinite set $A$ is in bijection with $A \cup \{A\}$, and by the unary predicate we can choose canonically an element in $A$. Any finite set is in bijection with a set of integers, hence we can also choose canonically an element in it.

Comment: @Quinn: It is enough to prove AC from Dedekind-infinite collections, so yes. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau, to choose canonically an element of $A$, wouldn't you have to choose a specific bijection? This is not an area I'm strong in, but I'm trying to understand how we go from "in bijection", which I think means "a bijection exists", to having a specific bijection to make a canonical choice.

Comment: @Joe: Just take $f(A)$ where $f$ is the canonical bijection between $A\cup\{A\}$ and $A$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, how do we know there is a bijection from $A \cup \{A\}$ to $A$ in the first place?

Comment: @Zuhair without choice, you don't know, that's why I talked about Dedekind-infinite sets, which are the sets having this property.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau, so you want to prove that every Dedekind-infinite set has a cannonical choice function, but is this enuogh to prove $AC$?

Comment: No idea. @Asaf seems to say that it is true, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: If $A$ is any (non-empty) set, consider $A\times\omega$, it's Dedekind-infinite, now if $f(A\times\omega\cup\{A\times\omega\})$ was $(a,n)$, simply choose $a$ from $A$. But I think that @QuinnLesquimau should post this answer, since they made the crucial observation.

Comment: @Asaf Thanks! I'll write it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I think you mean $f(A \times \omega)= (a,n)$ where $f$ is the cannonical bijection from $A \times \omega \cup \{A \times \omega\}$ to $A \times \omega$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comments by Asaf and myself:
We show that we can canonically choose an element in any non-empty set, implying the axiom of global choice. Let $A$ be a non-empty set. The set $A \times \omega$ is in bijection with $(A \times \omega) \cup \{A \times \omega\}$, because it is a Dedekind-infinite set. Choosing the bijection $f : (A \times \omega) \cup \{A \times \omega\} \to A \times \omega$ such that $C(f)$, we have some element $(a,n) = f(A \times \omega)$. The canonical element in $A$ is then $a$.